# number_to_currency gives "can't convert symbol to integer" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I'm using the method number_to_currency and i keep getting an error. Here's what i've tried:

```
= number_to_currency(233)
```

and:

```
= number_to_currency(233, locale: :en)
```

and they both raise he error:

```
can't convert Symbol into Integer
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: As the erro says, you are passing a symbol instead of an integer. Maybe if you post your code, we can check where it is assigning a symbol to the variable you are using.

Comment: paste your number_to_currency method

Comment: Hey guys. This isn't a custom method, I'm using the rails built in number_to_currency method. I even tried passing in 233.to_i.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously enough, the problem was in my en.yml file. The number_to_currency method translates using the 'number' path in the yml file and mine was wrong. I took the proper yml format from [here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en.yml).

Thanks to all helpers